# Integrate Worldpay in PHP

Tags: php, integration, worldpay

I want to integrate worldpay payment gateway in php(Test mode). I got the following code -

```
<form method="POST" name="BuyForm" action="https://secure- test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase">
<input type="hidden" value="yourinstid" name="instId">
<input type="hidden" value="yourcartid" name="cartId">
<input type="hidden" value="GBP" name="currency">
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="amount">
<input type="hidden" value="Product 1" name="desc">
<input type="hidden" value="100" name="testMode">
<input type=submit value="Buy Now">    
</form>
```

But in this code, installation Id is required and i have no merchant account and installation Id. Is it possible to implement this payment gateway without installation Id  eg - by using sandbox? Please suggest me the solution, if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no PHP in the question, nor any required for an answer. Yes, you will need those IDs, and yes, you should be able to get test ones to use with the sandbox. WorldPay's developer documentation should spell it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Worldpay with php you need to create the form where the customer will fill in the card details. Then in client side you will have to validate the data using their javascript api. 
Using the following code:

```
Worldpay.setClientKey(your api key here); 
var form = $('#payment')[0]; 
var _triggerWorldpayUseForm = function() {
    Worldpay.useForm(form, function (status, response) {
        if (response.error) {
            Worldpay.handleError(form, jQuery('#paymentErrors')[0], response.error);
        } else if (status != 200) {
            Worldpay.handleError(form, jQuery('#paymentErrors')[0], response);
        } else {
            var token = response.token;
            Worldpay.formBuilder(form, 'input', 'hidden', 'token', token);
            form.submit();
        }
    });
};
_triggerWorldpayUseForm();
```

If all details are correct then in php you can send the data to Worldpay and you will receive back a response.